# How can I center an image on top of a hero section?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a hero section I'm building that I need to place an image in the center of. The question is, how do I do that.

The image is what I need to achieve. The "Top 50" badge that's in the middle of the hero section is what I need to try and place over top of the "Banner" in the background.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/upenasyk/2/

The simple HTML and CSS code for the split hero section is below:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">            
        <div class="trsc-top-50-image col-lg-6">
        </div>
        <div class="trsc-top-50-text col-lg-6">
            <div class="hero-content split-hero-content">
                <div class="hero-content-inner">
                    <h3>What is the TrialScout Top 50?</h3>
                    <p>
                        The TrialScout Top 50 was established to recognize the elite clinical research programs driving American healthcare forward. Hospitals are selected based on their exceptional performance in quality, research
                        experience, infrastructure and patient experience.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        With TrialScout’s comprehensive global data set, hospitals are chosen by their assembled composite score. Composite scores are compiled with data collected from all active United States clinical research institutions and linked to numerous, other publicly available data sets, as well as ongoing, real-time direct patient feedback.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.trsc-top-50-image {
    background-image: url('images/TSTop50HeroImage.png');
    background-size: cover;

}

.trsc-top-50-text {
    background-image: linear-gradient(-135deg, #73c389, #5fc3c1);
}


.hero-content-inner {
    margin: 10%;
}

    .hero-content-inner h3 {
        /*margin: auto;*/
        color: #0A5D66;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }

    .hero-content-inner p {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: black;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the banner?

Comment: The banner is created via css. Edited with the CSS

Comment: Can you post the code for the CSS banner then?

Comment: Added the code for the section

Comment: You could try setting the css for the image to be `.myimg{top: 50%; left: 50%;z-index: 2}`.  I don't have all your code to test it, but if the img tag is inside the body tag and not another div, then this should work.  Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Tried. Doesn't seem to work: https://jsfiddle.net/upenasyk/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are using bootstrap. Anyways, you can put your logo in another div and within the `.row` and make it's position absolutely & push it by 50% from let and right. And again push it back of it's own width & height, so it will be positioned in the center both vertically any horizontally. Here is what I mean:

```
<div class="container">
    <!--previous content-->
    <div class="centerLogo">
        <img src="Your-Logo">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.centerLogo img{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

[Here is the live preview](https://codepen.io/shihab_codepen/pen/gEozwQ)

Comment: You need a position relative on .row class.

Comment: So, it's sitting on top of the section like I want. However, the issue that arises is that it needs to stay in the middle when It's placed when viewed on different desktop screen resolutions. Basically, I need it constrained to resize/move as the hero section moves

Comment: This is because you defined 2 separate columns for large devices and that is why it breaks down on smaller screen. You can replace `col-lg-6` with `col-6`. I also updated codepen.